# Firewall GPO not applying despite being enumerated by gpresult

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-xp, group-policy, windows-firewall

I have a need to open up the `admin$` share on all of my domain's client PC's and I am trying to do so using group policy. I defined computer policy for Windows Firewall with Advanced Security in a policy object linked to the appropriate container and added the appropriate rules. However, they are not being applied! I feel like I have tried all of the obvious steps: I've checked `gpresult` and the resulting set of policy is the way that I would expect it to look. I've `gpupdate /force` and `gpupdate /sync` on a few client computers, but no matter what I do they don't seem to respond to my changes. I know that other computer policies in the GPO *are* being applied so it is strange that these are not. I have also disabled exceptions on clients in the firewall GPO, but that doesn't seem to be applying either. Here is a screenshot of the `firewall.cpl` from a client:

[image: firewall.cpl 1]
[image: firewall.cpl 2]

Basically, although other options in the same GPO ARE applied for computer policy, the firewall settings seem to be ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you use the "Windows XP" Settings in:

> Computer Configuration -> Policies -> Administrative Templates ->
>   Network -> Network Connections -> Windows Firewall

The "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security" is for Windows 7.

Comment: Trying this out now... didn't realize that Windows Firewall with Advanced Security is W7 only

Comment: Actually, it's Vista and up / 2008 and up